# environment.ts not working in testing Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-test, angular-unit-test

Trying to write simple test in Angular 2 but getting error for `environment.ts` as below

> ERROR in ./web/environments/environment.ts Module build failed: Error:
>   web\environments\environment.ts is
>   missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'web-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Test App'; 

  constructor() {
    console.log(environment);
  }  
}
```

`app.component.spec.ts`

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it(`should 1+1`, () => {
    expect(1 + 1).toEqual(2);  //Success
  });
  it('should have component ', () => {
    const component = new AppComponent();  //Throws error
    // expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: it's because ng serve and ng test use different tsconfig.json. Can you post your tsconfig.spec.json?

Comment: I just have ```tsconfig.json``` but not ```tsconfig.spec.json```. I have created project using Angular  CLI.

Comment: look in the src folder

Answer (score 0):

create your `**.spec.ts` like this:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

describe('App', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 60000;
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                AppComponent
            ],
            imports: [
                AppModule
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should have component', async(() => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

Comment: Getting ```Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive AppComponent.```

Comment: Doing changes in answer, hope this help you